# Detecting microphone permissions using DetectRTC

Tags: javascript, detectrtc

I'm using a javascript library, [DetectRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/DetectRTC), to detect if the browser can use microphone and other stuff.

```
if(DetectRTC.isWebsiteHasMicrophonePermissions){
    //Is ok
}else{
    //Can't use microphone
}
```

The site has the permissions to use the microphone, but `DetectRTC.isWebsiteHasMicrophonePermissions` is still false. So I tried to print the object on the console and I get that `isWebsiteHasMicrophonePermissions` is set to true. But when I print the variable alone, it changes to false again.

```
console.log(DetectRTC); //isWebsiteHasMicrophonePermissions: true
console.log(DetectRTC.isWebsiteHasMicrophonePermissions) //false
```

Is this a bug or something? How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems the variable is `false` when the code is run but is set to `true` at some later point in time. When you inspect an object you get the _current_ state, not what the state was when the object was logged.

Comment: I tried to read the object at the beginning and at the end of the code, but stills true in the object and false alone.

Comment: Since the object is the same one, naturally that would be the case. Please reread the comment I made above — when you inspect an object, you get the state of the object at the time of inspection, not at the time of logging.

Comment: Ok, i tried this. I put the DetectRTC _inside_ the 'else'. It stills true in the objet

Comment: Inspect it by using JSON.stringify in the log and see what it says

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(DetectRTC));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As covered [in the docs](https://github.com/muaz-khan/DetectRTC#how-to-use-it), you need to use `DetectRTC.load()` to wait for detecting audio/video input/output devices.
See [this part of the docs](https://github.com/muaz-khan/DetectRTC#why-load-method) for further info.

```js
// This is too early
console.log(DetectRTC.hasMicrophone);

DetectRTC.load(() => {
  // This is reliable
  console.log(DetectRTC.hasMicrophone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/muaz-khan/DetectRTC/master/DetectRTC.js"></script>
```